# MySQL messed up apt-get?

Tags: apt, mysql

I tried to install MySQL for my localhost and I managed to break my dependencies, and I can **NOT** install anything

I have tried:

- Purging MySQL commons, client, server, ect.
- Removing MySQL commons, client, server, ect.
- apt-get update
- apt-get clean
- apt-get autoclean
- apt-get -f install

When I do apt-get -f install I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libmysqlclient18
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmysqlclient18
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/603 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,503 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 364284 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libmysqlclient18_5.5.40-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmysqlclient18:amd64 (5.5.40-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libmysqlclient18_5.5.40-                                                     
0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libmysqlclient18/changelog.Debian.gz',                  
which is different from other instances of package libmysqlclient18:amd64
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libmysqlclient18_5.5.40-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If you need more information tell me what to do

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override force fully this package using below command.

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libmysqlclient18_5.5.40-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

and than try `apt-get -f install`